# Django - Call a view on button click, not passing any information

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a button that needs to call a method in my views.py. It just needs to call a funtion, it doesn't need to send any information to the view, just call it.

This is the button:

```
        <a class="welcome-page-right hidden-xs hidden" href="#page-slider" data-slide="next" id="right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

I have used ajax to call a view already, im using ajax because i don't want the page to reload:

```
$("#Plane").onclick(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"{% url 'calculate' %}",
                 data: data,
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',

                 success: 
                       ....

            });
       });
```

Here i was sending info from a Form to the view. Now i need just to call a view, again without reloading the page.

I guess it must be something similar to the code above but because i know little to nothing about ajax and javascript it is quite difficult

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well calling a view is simply accomplished by accessing an URL, if you don't need any parameters just do not send anything.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"{% url 'calculate' %}",
    data: {},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    /*csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',*/
    success: function() {...}
});
```

You shouldn't need the csrf_token either.